# source-map-explorer for build with --vendor-chunk=false unable to map fully in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I would like to check the size distribution of my main.js file with `--vendor-chunk= false` but it halts at 99.82% with this:

> Unable to map 8836013 / 8851688 bytes (99.82%)

If I build without `--vendor-chunk=false.` It works fine. Is there any bug in the tool or I am doing something wrong?